# PouchDB sync API does not include changed documents

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB and I'm having problems because the changes reported by the `sync` API does not fit my expectations.
Reading the replication API I expected the `on change` event to include certain metadata about the changed documents. This it's explained here:

https://pouchdb.com/api.html#example-response-10

I know that is the API for replication, but the documentation at sync refers to it, so I will take it as source of truth. As you can see, according to documentation I will get an array of changed documents, so far so good.
However, instead, I'm getting the following:

```
{
"direction": "pull",
"change": {
    "ok": true,
    "start_time": "2017-06-24T18:14:39.290Z",
    "docs_read": 4,
    "docs_written": 4,
    "doc_write_failures": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "last_seq": "389-g1AAAAGjeJzLYWBgYMlgTmGQT0lKzi9KdUhJstDLSs1LLUst0kvOyS9NScwr0ctLLckBKmRKZEiy____f1YGc6J6LlCAPc0ixdQoOZWwdlQrzHBbkeQAJJPqobacANtimWJmYp5iRtgEoj2SxwIkGRqAFNCi_SCbfME2mRhYphmYG1PRPxCbDkBsAvvJE2yThaGlZappKmFTsgDmlIlz"
    }
}
```

The advantage is that I know the direction, the disadvantage is that I have to make my view to re-read all the documents just to get the most fresh version of the changes. There is no `docs` array anywhere

The way I'm triggering the replication is as follows:

```
database.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    filter: 'filtered_replication/only_tiddlers'
  }).on('change', function (info) {

    log( '===SYNC Change===');
    if (info.direction === 'pull'){
    // Refresh the full view because we don't know which documents should be updated
    }
  })
```

Comment: For all other API calls, you must include a `include_docs` option to get that functionality. Although I don't see it documented for that method, it's worth a try. In either case, it looks like the documentation needs to be updated. I'd suggest opening an issue [here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues).

Comment: @Flimzy there is already an issue opened by me: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6568 . You're right (according to the updated documentation) about the `include_docs` flag